# How to show image preview before uploading from controller in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, upload

i'm working in a project where i wanted to upload an image for Category.
The uploading part is working smooth.
what i want is before uploading, when user selects the image a preview of the selected image along with name of the image should be shown.
I'm pretty lost in this case.

Below is my view part:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/addCategory', 'method' => 'post', 'enctype'=>  'multipart/form-data']) !!}
        {{ csrf_field() }}
          @method('post')



          <div class="card ">
            <div class="card-header card-header-primary">
              <h4 class="card-title">{{ __('Add Category') }}</h4>
              <p class="card-category"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body ">
              <div class="row">
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{ __('Name') }}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                    <input class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="category" id="category" type="text" placeholder="{{ __('Name') }}" value="" required="true" aria-required="true" />

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{ __('Description') }}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                    <textarea class="md-textarea form-control" rows="5" name="desc" id="desc" type="text" placeholder="{{ __('Description') }}" value="" required="true" aria-required="true"></textarea>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="row">
                <label for="image" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Category Image</label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <input id="cat_image" type="file" class="form-control" name="cat_image">
                  <img src="" id="category-img-tag" width="200px" />   <!--for preview purpose -->
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer ml-auto mr-auto">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('Add Category') }}</button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Below is the controller part:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $cat = new Category;
        $cat->name = request('category');
        $cat->description = request('desc');
        if ($request->file('cat_image')) 
        {
            $categoryFile = $request->file('cat_image');
            $mimeType = $categoryFile->getClientOriginalName();
            $path =  public_path() . '/storage/category/';
            $categoryFile->move($path, $mimeType);

            $cat->cat_image = $mimeType;
        }   
        $cat->save();

        toastr()->success($cat->name,'Category added!');

        return redirect('/category');
    }
```

I have done uploading using controller instead of ajax because there were some complications...So kindly help me with image preview from controller.

[image]

Comment: Try upload image via js, without submitting form.

Comment: the js part of image upload has a lot of complication in mine thats why i go for controller

Answer (score 7):

**refer Below Link**

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/n51qyg96/)

**Add This function to your javascript code**

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.target.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#category-img-tag').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.target.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#cat_image").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

CHANGE YOUR blade.php file code like  `<img src="#" id="category-img-tag" width="200px" />`

```
      <div class="row">
        <label for="image" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Category Image</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <input id="cat_image" type="file" class="form-control" name="cat_image">
          <img src="#" id="category-img-tag" width="200px" />   <!--for preview purpose -->
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: please mark as verified this answer if its help for you Thank you   @kuku